# Intersection of two layers, attribute-table stays empty QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, intersection

[image]I am trying to intersect two layers to calculate proportional distances of the two layers.. However, the attribute table remains empty after the intersection. To tool runs fine and no error is shown.

Comment: Do features actually overlap, so an intersection could happen?

Comment: Add a screenshot + details

Comment: @Erik Yes most of them do overlap. I added a screenshot

Comment: Intersection is the wrong tool to use when working with two line layers. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I would also ask what are you trying to achieve which might affect any suggestions.  As a general suggestion you might try the Split with lines tool twice changing input and split layers.  You may need to recalculate lengths on the result using $length.  You also might look at the Overlap Analysis tool.

Comment: Are both layers in the same CRS?